# Is it possible to view a movie in 2 locations at once?

Tags: video, sync, vlc-media-player

Is it possible to view a movie at the same time using my phone, while it's playing on my laptop? If possible, vlc would be my first choice, but I could use other players as well.

EDIT: to make it a bit clearer. Whatever is shown on the laptop, I'd like to see on my phone's video player.

Comment: your requirement is unclear. Do you want to watch a movie on two devices simultaniously, so they are synced at the same playing position, or do you simply want to open a movie independently on two devices at the same time.

Comment: Synced at the same time. Whatever is shown on the laptop, i'd like to see from the phone at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a network stream using VLC and view the broadcast from both your PC and your phone.

> ### Broadcasting a Stream
>
> To start broadcasting a network stream, click the Media menu in VLC and select Stream.
>
> [image]
>
> In the Open Media dialog, select the media you want to stream. You can select one or more files on the Files tab, select a CD or DVD on the Disc tab, or even capture video from a specific device on the Capture Device tab. For example, you could stream your desktop by selecting Desktop on the Capture Device tab.
>
> Click the Stream button after selecting your media.
>
> [image]
>
> The Stream Output window will appear. The first pane just lists the media source you selected – click Next to continue.
>
> [image]
>
> On the Destination Setup pane, you’ll need to choose a destination for your stream. For example, you can select HTTP to listen for connections – other computers can connect to your computer and watch the stream. You can also select UDP to broadcast to a specific IP address or range of IP addresses.
>
> After selecting your destination, click the Add button. You may also want to activate the Display locally check box – if you do, you’ll see and hear the media being streamed on your local computer, so you’ll know it’s playing correctly.
>
> [image]
>
> After adding a destination, you’ll be able to customize its settings. With the HTTP destination, you could specify a custom path – but the default one will work fine.
>
> You can also tweak the transcoding settings – by transcoding to a lower quality, VLC can save network bandwidth.
>
> [image]
>
> Click Next to continue to the Option Setup pane – you probably don’t need to tweak any of the advanced options here. To start streaming, click the Stream button.
>
> [image]
>
> If you selected the Display locally option, the media will start playing locally on your computer.
>
> If you have a firewall enabled, ensure that VLC is an allowed program or no computers will be able to connect. If you’re trying to stream over the Internet, you may also need to forward ports on your router.
>
> ### Connecting to a Stream
>
> To tune in to a stream, click the Media menu in VLC on another computer and select Open Network Stream.
>
> [image]
>
> Assuming you used HTTP, enter an address like http://IP.Address:8080. See this post if you need help finding the other system’s IP address.
>
> (If you specified a custom path for your HTTP stream in the Path box, you’ll need to specify the custom path here. For example, if you specified /path as your custom path, you’d enter http://IP.Address:8080/path in the box here.)
>
> [image]
>
> After clicking Play, the stream should start playing. To control playback remotely, try setting up VLC’s web interface. If you encounter an error, make sure VLC isn’t being blocked by a firewall on the streaming system.
>
> [Source (HowToGeek)](http://www.howtogeek.com/118075/how-to-stream-videos-and-music-over-the-network-using-vlc/)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how fast your connection is, you could use the remote desktop chrome extension and android app from Google.

Download the remote desktop extension for chrome and also download the remote desktop app from google play store. Sync both machines and then you can play the movie in your computer, and see it in your android phone/ tablet

Comment: How do you do it precisely?

Comment: Download the remote desktop extension for chrome and also download the remote desktop app from google play store. Sync both machines and then you can play the movie in your computer, and see it in your android phone/ tablet.

Comment: That should probably be in your answer.